# how to get value [object][object]

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

when i try to access my object {{result}} in my view, which i send from my express js server, its only showing [object][object]
is there anyone know how to get its value in JSON format?

this is my html code

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">

      console.log({{result}});
    </script>
```

and this is my server code

```js
const express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connection = require('../db.js');
const app = express();

app.use(session({
    secret: 'fffdfee',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
}));

module.exports = {
   
    
     getGraphQuis: function(req, res){
        connection.query('select questionnaireresult.*, questionnaire .typequestionnaire from questionnaire inner join questionnaireresult on questionnaire.id = questionnaire.idquestionnaire where?', {
            idquestionnaire: req.params.id,
        }, function(err, rows, fields){
            if(rows[0]){
                
                res.render('stakeholder/grafik-result', {result: rows});
            }else {
                res.render('stakeholder/alert')
            }
        });
    },
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use:

```
{{result | json}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON.stringify({{ result }})`

This will output the value into a JSON string

```js
var obj = {a: 1}

document.getElementById('1').innerHTML = obj
document.getElementById('2').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj)
```

```html
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
```